# IONIC 2 - <ion-segment> <div> Google Map not showing

Tags: google-maps, ionic2

The google maps is displayed when the page is loaded.
But when the ion-segment is toggled , the maps is not displayed.
Below is my ionic 2 code:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar no-border-top>
    <ion-segment [(ngModel)]="social" (ionChange)="segementChangeAction()">
      <ion-segment-button value="activity">
        Map
      </ion-segment-button>
      <ion-segment-button value="messages">
        Messages
      </ion-segment-button>
    </ion-segment>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>



<ion-content no-bounce>
  <div [ngSwitch]="social">
    <div *ngSwitchCase="'activity'">
        <div #map id="map"></div>
    </div>
    <div *ngSwitchCase="'messages'">
      Some text.....        
    </div>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because ngSwitchCase removes the map's div from the DOM when ion-segment is toggled. Do this:

```
<div [ngSwitch]="social">
  <div [style.display]="social === 'activity' ? 'block' : 'none'">
    <div #map id="map"></div>
  </div>
  <div *ngSwitchCase="'messages'">
    Some text.....        
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to make it work in Ionic 3 the accepted answer i´ve to make a little adjustment adding height: 100% to the container:

```
<div [ngSwitch]="social">
  <div [style.display]="social === 'activity' ? 'block' : 'none'" style="height: 100%">
  <div #map id="map"></div>
</div>
<div *ngSwitchCase="'messages'">
  Some text.....        
</div>
```